# Android webView not displaying all the content

Tags: android, html, css, webview, chromium

As the title says I have a web view which displays part of a webpage that I created and placed in my server, but some of the content of it isn't being displayed, nothing special just some unordered list tags.

I've tested it with the browser that comes with Android and it does the same, but if I open it with Chrome in the device it does shows... From the computer usin chrome and safari it also shows ok.

I think maybe a user agent, something like chromium could solve the problem but I don't really know how to implement it. I've tried all these but without success:

```
final WebView webS = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webV);
webS.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
//webS.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
webS.loadUrl("http://mywebpage.com");
//webS.setInitialScale(100);
//webS.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
//webS.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
//webS.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

WebChromeClient client = new WebChromeClient();
webS.setWebChromeClient(client);
```

Here's the structure of the html:

```
<!doctype html>
   <html>
     <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">

     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1">
      <title></title>
       <link href="CSS/....css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
     </head>

      <body>
          <div id="wrapper">
                <p></p>

                <ul class="">
                      <a href="">
                              <li>
                                 <div class=""><img src="images/....png"></div>
                                  text <span class="">text</span>
                                  <div class="">text</div>
                                  <div class="">text</div>

                              </li>

                              <li>
                                 <div class=""><img src="images/....png"></div>
                                  text <span class="">text</span>
                                  <div class="">text</div>
                                  <div class="">text</div>

                              </li>
                         </a> 
                   </ul>


                </div>
             </body>
          </html>
```

The part that is not being shown is the one between anchor tags...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

remove the minimum-scale=1 to maximum-scale=1 in the meta tag